# How to upgrade a MSSQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

As we were updating a service on an older enviroment, we experienced compartibility issues because the service we were updating is working with MSSQL Server 2008+ only. Now we have the issue that we have a huge amount of data and we somehow want to keep it and if possible not touch it. Is there any possibility to upgrade a MSSQL Server 2003 to a MSSQL Server 2008 R2 without exporting the database and manipulating the data?

Comment: Why would you go to a RC2? 2008 is old - and RC2 is a RELEASE CANDIDATE. It is not a released version. This makes little to no sense.

Comment: @TomTom: Surely he means **2008 R2**.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it was r2

Comment: So, why would anyone get a 2008 r2 when in reality the current version is 2014?

Comment: Because it is a test-enviroment of a live system which we use for developing. We want it to have the same specs as the live enviroment

Comment: @TomTom Let's be a little bit realistic, there are very few real production environments rolling out 2014. True 2008r2 is dated, but the current real stable version being used in most situations is 2012.

Comment: Lets be realistic. If you run a system falling behind then you do big leaps. I would definitely go to 2014 right now - it is there, it is stable and it means for some years I have no reason to upgrade again. 2008 R2 is - the next upgrade happening when? It can not be in support that much longer.

Comment: @TomTom 2008 R2 is also the most recent version that allows per-processor licensing, rather than forcing you to pay per-core.  Hard to justify doubling or quadrupling your SQL server license costs based on the new features offered in 2012 or 2014.

Comment: @TomTom stability doenst matter in this case. I want it to be a 2008 because I need it to be. I can´t run a test system of a live enviroment with totally different specs and presettings.

Comment: If you people downvote, it would be nice to know why. Just for improving my question.

Comment: @Horius I downvoted your question (sorry). Because I feel like there is a lot of documentation out there on the subject and a google search would have shown that quite easily. Having done quite a few upgrades of sql server in my first job, I feel like if I was able to find the documentation online with a few hours of research 6 years ago, you should be able to today. If there was any indication of research in your question I wouldn't have downvoted it.

Comment: @TomTom by the way i find it hilarious how you just ignore my point. You say "2014 is better" - I agree with that. But as i said(as you ignored) it should be an actual copy of a life system. If you think about it a second, updating a life system is not as easy as it sounds because nobody can work while the update is in progress. Also, there could be so many cases of causing crashes while updating the life system which would cost tons of time to reply the backup to the live system. So we keep 2008 as long as possible and the test system has to be the same version, no matter which is better.

Comment: @Reaces Thanks for the feedback, maybe i were just to stupid to google so thats definetly my fault

Comment: @Horius It has nothing to do with you. It's a measure to determine how useful the question would be to people compared to the already available information on the subject. I'm not downvoting you or your capabilities. If I offended you I apologise. (But will still leave the downvote in place)

Comment: I meant that I agree with you and I am not offended by the downvote nor your opinion. I know that this is for rating the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[By upgrading it, essentially](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg454217.aspx).

You have the option of an in-place upgrade, where you run the installer on your existing instance and upgrading it, or doing a migration upgrade, which essentially consists of standing up a new SQL server instance and moving your databases over.  The in-place upgrade is easier, but riskier - use the ["SQL Upgrade Advisor"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978) and make sure you have restore-tested backups of your SQL server if you go this route - but really, neither route is particularly risky or difficult.

If your issue is related to syntax or features added with sql server 2008r2 that your 2003 based database does not support, you will also want to [check your database compatibility level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) after the upgrade.